# How can I find rotation angles (pitch, yaw, roll) from perspective transofmation coefficients

Tags: opencv, matrix, 3d, projective-geometry

I have two 2d quads (each represented using 4 xy pairs), one of them is a perspective transformation of the other. How can I use these quads to deduce the rotations (pitch, yaw, roll) that caused the perspective distortion?

Notice that I used the cvGetPerspectiveTransform() which returns the perspective transformation coefficients in the form of a 3x3 matrix. I am able to use such coefficients to map a point from one space to another. However, it is the rotation angles which I'm concerned about knowing.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Hasan.

Comment: May be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection

Answer (score 0):

My algorithm was
1) calculate 3d coordinate of to quads (example show in  [Calculating rectangle 3D coordinate with coordinate its shadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643692/calculating-rectangle-3d-coordinate-with-coordinate-its-shadow))
2) take to point of first and corresponded two points of second calculate quaternion(see first reference I post in it reference to answer)
3) from quaternion calculate  rotation matrix, angle.