# calculate quaternion by coordinate 2 points of object in two positions

Tags: 3d, rotation, quaternions

Object rotate in 3D. I have rotation center and coordinate of 2 point in rotate and not rotate position. Calculate quaternion that rotate object from first position to two position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to vector OA' and OB' in first position of object
OA and OB in second position
Q vector part quaternion Q<sub>0</sub> scalar part

**fig.1**
[image: object with 2 point before and after rotation]

**COMMENT**
OA

OB - dot vector product
OAxOB - cross vector product

Quaternion of rotation object from first positon to second was:
**1 case**
If OA

OB'-OB*OA' not equal zero, then
Q=Q<sub>0</sub>*[(OA-OA')x(OB-OB')]/[OA*OB'-OA'*OB],

 where Q<sub>0</sub><sup>-2</sup>=([(OA-OA')x(OB-OB')]/[OA*OB'-OA'

OB])<sup>2</sup>+1

If OA

OB'-OB*OA'=0, then

**2 case**

if [OA'+OA]x[OB'+OB] not equal zero and OB-OB' not equal zero,
    then
exist m that OA-OA'=m*(OB-OB'). Search it.
Q=n*(m*OB'+OA'), 

where n=Q<sub>0</sub>*(OB-OB')<sup>2</sup>/(2*OB*[OA'xOB'])
Q<sub>0</sub><sup>-2</sup>=(OB-OB')<sup>4</sup>*(OB'+OA')<sup>2</sup>/(2*OB*[OA'xOB'])<sup>2</sup>+1

If OA*OB'-OB*OA'=0 and [OA+OA']x[OB+OB']=0
 
**3 case**
If OB+OB'not equal zero, then
Q=(OB+OB')/|OB+OB'|, Q<sub>0</sub>=0
else

**4 case**
OB+OB'=0
Q=([OB']x[OA'])/|[OB']x[OA']|, Q<sub>0</sub>=0

From quaternion we can calculate rotation matrix or Euler angles

Answer (score 0):

Look at answer to similar question
[How to find correct rotation from one vector to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828801/how-to-find-correct-rotation-from-one-vector-to-another/22146038#22146038)

Your difference that second vector "up" is not perpendicular to first "dir". Just make it and problem solved