# How to fix image perspective distortion and rotation with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, perspective, distortion

I have some images that takes using mobile phone. Is there any JavaScript library which can straighten the photo of a paper and flatten it? For example I want to create a rectangular image without any distortion from this image.

**In the other words** I want to know how to fix perspective distortion and rotation with JavaScript?

For example I found below sample image from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1022338/Scan-Anything-Anywhere-Any-Time) article:

[image]

How to fix this type of image with javascript?

Comment: `canvas` may have the tools required to manipulate an image - but wait, you flagged it node.js, so there is no browser goodness available - you'll need something pretty intelligent, it has to detect issues and fix them with no user interaction

Comment: This is either wa-a-a-ay too broad for Stack Overflow, or you're asking for something already made that can do this which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JaromandaX ,
Yes I need a way that work without user interaction.

Comment: Realize [my algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643692/calculating-rectangle-3d-coordinate-with-coordinate-its-shadow) on java . Calculate quaternion then rotate image. Any question - ask

Comment: I desperately need that too!!! Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: Hi everyone I have done it, please check my answer below ,let me know if I need any improvements

Answer (score 4):

There is no need of any extra npm package, this can be achieved by creation a irregular crop box, first load the image into a canvas, one should adjust 4 cropping points over image, put the portion into a regular rectangular canvas.

Follow this link for detailed code and steps [Image Perspective correction using javascript and opencv](http://www.recompile.in/2019/11/image-perspective-correction-using.html)

Here is the demo

[image: perspective correction javascript]

```
let dst = new cv.Mat();
let dsize = new cv.Size(imageHeight, imageWidth);
let srcTri = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, pointsArray);
let dstTri = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, [0, 0, imageHeight, 0, imageHeight, imageWidth, 0, imageWidth]);
let M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(srcTri, dstTri);
cv.warpPerspective(src, dst, M, dsize, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, new cv.Scalar());
document.getElementById('imageInit').style.display = "none"
cv.imshow('imageResult', dst);
```

Comment: I tried to use your sample code and it seems working with the provided image. But when I changed the image source, somehow it doesn't transform the image as expected (Perspective Transformation). Anything specific required to do or missed something, not sure?

Comment: OP is asking for automatically fixing the image, while this requires the user to drag the crop handles themselves.

Comment: It's almost perfect solution, but:

a) it's not working automatically like @AbyxDev said

b) It's depended from OpenCV - very large and slow (in JS) lib

Answer (score 3):

Looks like https://www.npmjs.com/package/perspective-transform is what you are looking for.

> Create functions to map points from one arbitrary quadrilateral to another and vice versa with the inverse

Answer (score 1):

[JSFeat](https://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/) can do that for you. There even is an example for perspective distortion. You'll have to add/compute the source and destination points yourself.